# Variable of reference type in constant expressions

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Here, at http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#2.7 it can be read

> 3 -
> A variable is usable in constant expressions after its initializing declaration is encountered if it is a constexpr variable, **or it is of
> reference type** or of const-qualified integral or enumeration type, and
> its initializer is a constant initializer.

Well, the case is that I cannot figure myself an example for the case where the variable is of reference type.

In

```
int main()
{
    static const double& ds = 0.5;
    constexpr double cds = ds;
}
```

Visual Studio 16.1.2 complains:

> expression must have a constant value.
>
> the value of variable (declared at line 11) cannot be used as a constant

But, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is not legal in C++17 because it contains a `constexpr` variable whose initialization requests lvalue-to-rvalue conversion and it is not one of the listed exceptions: (C+17 [expr.const]/2.7)

> an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion (7.1) unless it is applied to
>
> - a non-volatile glvalue of integral or enumeration type that refers to a complete non-volatile const object with a preceding initialization, initialized with a constant expression, or
> - a non-volatile glvalue that refers to a subobject of a string literal, or
> - a non-volatile glvalue that refers to a non-volatile object defined with constexpr , or that refers to a non-mutable subobject of such an object, or
> - a non-volatile glvalue of literal type that refers to a non-volatile object whose lifetime began within the evaluation of `e`;

You should find the code compiles if you change to an integer type instead of `double`.

---

The text you quote is from a draft and as such, may or may not eventually form part of some standard.

Comment: In Compiler Explorer [https://godbolt.org/z/dlbXF4](https://godbolt.org/z/dlbXF4) gcc 9.1 and msvc v19.20 can compile it, while clang 8.0 fails. (??)

Comment: @Loreto that's a common situation with draft proposals